# Where does forward voltage drop in a diode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

To simplify the picture, I would start with an n-type Schottky diode. It has two junctions: one rectifying and one non-rectifying (ohmic contact).

When the diode is forward biased, it conducts current, but it has a small voltage drop, say, 0.3V. Most, if not all, textbooks will tell you that this voltage drops on the rectifying junction.

To me, it seems more likely that the forward voltage drops on the ohmic contact. Has anyone personally measured the voltage drop on the rectifying junction? If not, can anyone suggest how it can be done (if it can be done)?

The same question is applicable to p-n junction diodes.

Comment: Draw the band diagram through the diode. Why is the ohmic contact taking the voltage drop across the depletion region? (Now, there will be ohmic voltage drops in the $n$ and $p$ portions away from the junction itself, just from the material resistivity.)

Comment: Making good ohmic contacts to a solid state diode is indeed an important detail in the real world manufacturing of diodes, and one which I believe has been effectively dealt with. The textbooks you're reading are just focussing on the physics of the junction itself.

Comment: I am not talking about resistive voltage drop. I am talking about the forward voltage drop. The textbooks assume that the ohmic contact has very low resistance in both directions and don't bother to include it in the band diagrams, as if it was just a metal-to-metal contact. So, I am supposed to believe that the forward voltage drop occurs on the forward biased junction. Perhaps. But is it possible to prove by direct measurements? If not, I can speculate that the voltage drop occurs on the ohmic contact: after all, for a forward biased Schottky, the ohmic contact is reverse biased.

Comment: Not an expert on metal-semiconductor contacts, but I thought that Schottky contacts and ohmic contacts are different types of contacts, with Schottky contacts being rectifying and non-ohmic (since ohmic contacts should show symmetric current behavior under voltage reversal). So, according to my knowledge and recollection, I don't think that true ohmic contacts are ever reverse biased.

Comment: "Not all metal–semiconductor junctions form a rectifying Schottky barrier; a metal–semiconductor junction that conducts current in both directions without rectification, perhaps due to its Schottky barrier being too low, is called an ohmic contact." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_barrier

Comment: As far as I know, the main difference between rectifying and non-rectifying (ohmic) metal-semiconductor contacts is the doping level near the contact. Here is how I think it might work:The doping level affects the strength of the field across the boundary of a reverse biased junction. If the field is strong enough, the fastest electrons will be able to escape from the metal to n-type semiconductor (get into conductive band).

Comment: Now, that requires energy and that's why I think that the voltage should drop on a reverse biased junction (ohmic or not), i.e., where the work is done. When the high energy electrons reach the forward biased rectifying junction, they just fall to the metal, with the potential energy converting to kinetic energy and heat.

Comment: The analogy is a horizontal pipe with a raised section in the middle. If we pump the water through such pipe, the pressure will drop on the rising, not on the falling, end of the raised section. If the doping level is not sufficiently high, the field across the boundary is weak and the electrons cannot escape. This interpretation can explain a lot of things, but it sounds too simple to be true. That's why I would like to actually measure the voltage drop and put this thing to rest.

Comment: *"To me, it seems more likely that the forward voltage drops on the ohmic contact"* - wouldn't that imply that the forward voltage drop is (ideally) linear in the current?

Comment: It should (by the sound of it:), but I'd like to measure it to be sure.

Comment: You view of how ohmic contacts work is not correct.